# Test server with Django returns different AJAX results than with Apache server

Tags: python, django, browser

Right now I am learning how to do AJAX calls within my Django project. Right now I have a html page which makes a AJAX call to a page that returns a JSON response.

My problem is that when I go to the ajax page, hosted by Apache, returning the response, the response is that of an old configuration of the site. When I use the test site with python manage.py runserver, the ajax value returns corresponds to what is defined in the views.py file.

The ajax response from the site page via Apache is unresponsive to my changes to the code while the test server is. I do not understand why this is. This is reminiscent of a previous problem I encountered where there was a redirect in my url.py file which was unresponsive to changes in the same way. It did start to work and I thought it was because I cleared my browser history. That was not helpful in this case.

This is my view which contains the AJAX response

```
def validate_username(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username', None)
    data = { 
        'is_taken': User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists()
    }   
    if data['is_taken']:
        data['error_message'] = 'A user with this username already exists.'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I know this response is called because I can go to url define with this view and get the old view.

I am not sure what would be of use but I can provide the html template and the Apache server configuration if needed. Or anything else.

This is my Apache relevant configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/django_projects/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /srv/django_projects/myapp

Alias /static/ /srv/django_projects/myapp/static/

<Directory /srv/django_projects/myapp>
Require all granted

#<Files wsgi.py>
#Require all granted
#</Files>
</Directory>
```

EDIT
I do have the correct response now but I do not understand why it did not change when I reloaded Apache. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The Django development server watches your code for changes and reloads. This won't happen if you're serving your application via Apache - which would be an unusual thing to do in development and is more suited to production use. Is the new version of the code running on the system the Apache server is running on? How is Apache serving the Django application - through uWSGI, gunicorn, ...?

Comment: I just added my httpd.conf. The new code should be in the contents of the directory shown in my configuration.

Comment: are you using supervisor ?

Comment: You need to restart the wsgi application so that your code is reloaded. You probably should not need to run your application like this in development; just run it through the dev server and then figure out the apache stuff for prod.